# How to use "try Catch" in flutter for error handling

Tags: typescript, dart, error-handling, flutter-web

I have an API endpoint that returns an error response when I insert a duplicate entry. I need to capture this error response using the try catch so I can pass this response as a toast message. Here is the api response structure and the api consumption code I have tried:
[image]

```js
// companyService
Future<Object?> createCompany(Company company) async {
try {
  var content = jsonEncode(company.toJson());
  accessToken = await sharedPref.read(key);
  searchUrl = "$baseUrl/company";
  var response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(searchUrl),
    body: content,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer $accessToken",
    },
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    return company;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('objectError: $e');
  return e;    
}

// companyFactory
createCompany(
  name,
  domain,
  address,
  cityId,
) async {
  final company = Company(
    name: name,
    domain: domain,
    address: address,
    cityId: cityId,
  );     
try {
  CompanyService requests = CompanyService();
  await requests.createCompany(company);
  return company;
} catch (e) {
  print('objectError: $e');
  return e;
}
  }
```

Comment: Well, you haven't explained what's the problem with your current code. Also, you are using: `if (response.statusCode == 201)` did you mean to use code `200` instead? Why not add a `try`/`catch` block in that line of code?

Comment: The problem is how to use the try/catch block in place of the if/else, I actually omitted that part where I have included the try/catch because it isn't working for me. So let me update the code with the  try catch block. As for the status code 201, that's actually correct, if the create request is succesful thus the request has been created, it should return a 201